# Adding functionality to macOS pre-boot process

Tags: startup, filevault, efi

Is anyone familiar with adding functionality to the macOS pre-boot process? I'm trying to supplement FileVault's functionality so that it can integrate with a user directory service, which isn't really an Apple-supported or well-documented type of task.

My goal is to allow remote users to unlock and login to the device without having a local account setup yet. FileVault currently only allows users with existing local accounts to unlock a device. I'm working on a Mac Pro running macOS High Sierra 10.13.6 with APFS.

Based on [Apple's documentation of the boot process](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/KernelProgramming/booting/booting.html) and [Eclectic Light Co's articles on the topic](https://eclecticlight.co/2018/08/25/booting-the-mac-visual-summary/), my understanding is that pre-boot procedures such as kernel loading and FileVault decryption are handled by the `boot.efi` file in the Preboot APFS disk partition.

So as far as I can tell, I need to modify how `boot.efi` works to achieve my goals. Is there a way I can build my own `boot.efi` with additional functionality and then safely replace the existing one, or can I add a supplemental EFI file with additional functionality that is run in conjunction with `boot.efi`?

Along those lines, the only resource I have found so far is Piker Alpha's [boot loader source tree](https://github.com/Piker-Alpha/macosxbootloader/tree/Sierra), but I'm hesitant to use this project since it appears to be outdated/only for HFS+ based Macs (and also only builds using Visual Studio).

Does anyone have other resources or suggestions on how I can modify macOS pre-boot procedures?

Comment: I know you can use your own bootloader as long as you're not using one of the newer secure boot machines, take a look at something like rEFIt if you haven't already. I haven't seen a customized version of Apple's own bootloader, but don't immediately see why it wouldn't be possible if you have the source.

Comment: Related [What does boot.efi actually do?](//apple.stackexchange.com/q/98315) And conceptually it looks like re-inventing a wheel when your cart needs a driver? So, what is the real goal for having it "integrate with a user directory service"? Remote or auto-decryption?

Comment: @LangLangC my goal is to allow remote users to unlock and login to the device without having a local account setup yet. FileVault currently only allows users with existing local accounts to unlock a device.

Comment: Please [edit] that explicitness into the question. Also check out https://github.com/grahamgilbert/crypt & https://github.com/grahamgilbert/crypt-server and see if that and on that level is approaching your goals?

Comment: @LangLangC edit made. Unfortunately Crypt isn't quite powerful enough for my needs. I really need to change the way FileVault handles user accounts itself. I do not need remote key management.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apple doesn’t prevent you from running other EFI unless you have trusted OS / T2 chips. You can disable these security steps on Mojave and current T2, but that’s pretty manual and not automated.

You’ll want to look at tools like [BootRunner](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/boot-runner/) or the two canoes [MDS with automaton](https://twocanoes.com/products/mac/mac-deploy-stick/) to automate the pre-boot environment for all modern Mac hardware and modern macOS.

Much easier to handle things with the tools Apple gives than trying to re-engineer EFI / customize things that don’t have sanctioned support. Extending PAM / authentication is long supported, but changing EFI is not something most enterprises take on in my experience.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I had come to the conclusion that modifying the EFI was definitely a while goose chase, and I appreciate the suggestions!